# Can we treat finite and infinite primes in scheme theory?

Tags: number-theory

In Number Theory, I know we have analogy to geometry by considering infinite primes not only Spec $\mathcal{O}_K$ (and I heard the point of view bring the Riemann-Roch theory).

My question is can we treat this point of view in the scheme theory? That is, can we define a proper scheme structure on Spec $\mathcal{O}_K \cup \{$infinite primes$\}$?